# Get contents before a colon

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file on Linux where the contents are like below:

```
help.helloworld.com:latest.world.com
dev.helloworld.com:latest.world.com
```

I want to get the contents before the colon like below:

```
help.helloworld.com
dev.helloworld.com
```

How can I do that within the terminal?

Comment: The `grep` utility is used for looking for lines matching regular expressions. You could possibly use it here, but it would be more appropriate to use a tool that extracts data from fields given some delimiter, such as the `cut` utility.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to take out the word "grep" and replace it with "find" in the title and "get" in the question body, to avoid the X/Y issue of assuming `grep` is the right tool to solve the actual problem.

Comment: All I can say is that the contents before the colon is much better than the contents after the colon ;-).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is what `cut` is for:

```
$ cat file
help.helloworld.com:latest.world.com
dev.helloworld.com:latest.world.com
foo:baz:bar
foo

$ cut -d: -f1 file
help.helloworld.com
dev.helloworld.com
foo
foo
```

You just set the delimiter to `:` with `-d:` and tell it to only print the 1st field (`-f1`).

Answer (score 20):

Or an alternative:

```
$ grep -o '^[^:]*' file
help.helloworld.com
dev.helloworld.com
```

This returns any characters beginning at the start of each line (`^`) which are no colons (`[^:]*`).

Answer (score 19):

Would definitely recommend `awk`:

```
awk -F ':' '{print $1}' file
```

Uses `:` as a field separator and prints the first field.

Answer (score 5):

### updated answer

Considering the following file `file.txt`:

```
help.helloworld.com:latest.world.com
dev.helloworld.com:latest.world.com
no.colon.com
colon.at.the.end.com:
```

You can use `sed` to remove everything after the colon:

```bsh
sed -e 's/:.*//' file.txt
```

This works for all the corner cases pointed out in the comments—if it
ends in a colon, or if there is no colon, although these weren't mentioned
in the question itself. Thanks to @Rakesh Sharma, @mirabilos, and @Freddy
for their comments. Answering questions is a great way to learn.

Comment: `sed -e 's/:.*//' file.txt` is another way with Posix sed.

Comment: `sed -ne 'y/:/\n/;P' file.txt` also can be used.

Comment: Make `.+` to `.*`

Comment: @Randy Joselyn Since there's an implicit `if` in the `s///p` syntax, you need to modify your regex to take care of lines with no colons, something like, `sed -nEe 's/([^:]*)(:.*|)/\1/p'`. Note this requires `GNU sed` but since anyway you are on GNU sed so this shouldn't matter.

Comment: This answer could have been my favourite, but the ERE are unnecessary. `sed -n '/:/s/^\([^:]*\):.*$/\1/p` (add `--posix` if you use GNU sed, just to spite the extensionism of theirs)

Answer (score 4):

> Requires GNU grep. It would not work with the default grep on
>   e.g. macOS or any of the other BSDs.

Do you mean like this:

```
grep -oP '.*(?=:)' file
```

Output:

```
help.helloworld.com
dev.helloworld.com
```

Comment: If there are two or more colons on the line, this will print everything until the last one, so not what the OP needs. Try `echo foo:bar:baz | grep -oP '.*(?=:)'`. This will work for the OP's example, but not for the general case as described in the question.

Comment: there is only one colon and its working fine , but thanks for the update

Answer (score -2):

You could achieve this with bash string handling, by removing the longest match from the string directly for each line read like so:

```
for line in $(cat inputfile); do echo "${line%%:*}"; done
```

This might be a useful alternative if you are parsing the file in a shell script (though I suspect using cut might be more efficient).

Comment: please read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/72456)

Answer (score -2):

In pure POSIX shell without using external commands, I'd do:

```bsh
#/bin/sh
IFS=:
while read -r a _; do
  echo "$a"
  done < file.txt
unset IFS
```

Comment: please read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/72456)